# Java - Need Verbose GC logging to Separate Files

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I understand there's -Xloggc option exists for outputting GC output to separate file.  But it doesn't work for me.  I've 16 java processes with same main running on one machine so I can't really hardcode file path.   Ideally I want to specify only directory where separate pid specific files are created.  Is that possible?   Note I don't want GC output mixed with stdout and hence a need for separate file.

Version : SunJDK 1.5_13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you change the loggc directory with

```
-Xloggc:/path/`date +%Y%M%d%H%m%S`.gc.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you mix standard out and GC and then grep out what you want? There should be much coming out of standard out, or at least not much that you couldn't redirect elsewhere if you are using a logging framework.

Comment: My processes have too much stdout so mixing will not be as good.  Is there a way to produce only critical GC output - perhaps only Full GC ?

Comment: But the GC messages should be have predicatable prefixes so they ought to be easy to grep out. Are you trying to log for development/debugging or do you want this for actual running in production?